# bumped to the homepage by Community?

Tags: discussion

Often this is happening: "bumped to the homepage by Community", when looking at "active" questions.

But what are we supposed to do with it?

Comment: @MrZak, ok, but what is the consequence? Just upvoting an answer will validate it as the good answer? Or are we supposed to do anything else? And how many UV are needed to solve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/238438):

> - The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that [have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/155074).
>
>   - Questions are [picked randomly from the top-viewed inactive questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690).
>   - The number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 1 per hour on Meta, and 2 per hour on Super User and Server Fault. The default for a new site is [1 per hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511).

The idea is to give attention to questions which may have been buried.
So if you see one, treat it as you would any other question:

- Comment on the question and answer(s) to request clarification etc.
- Edit the question/answer(s) to clarify/rephrase/correct etc.
- If you feel they deserve it, vote on the questions/answer(s) (up or down) etc.
- Write your own answer
- etc.